# set header of tabitem based on content in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, tabitem

Initially I thought that it will be a very trivial functionality but now I am not able to implement it.

My requirement is simple. I am programmatically setting the content of a `TabItem`. The content will be usercontrols. I want to set the text of the header of the `TabItem` based on the content.

Content doesn’t have a changed event so I am confused as to on which event should I write code.

Also I’m not able to find any style or anything on the net.

Any suggestions? Please help. Thanks in advance.

PS: Please let me know if you need any further information from my side.

Comment: Please supply any code / xaml you have already tried.

Comment: why don't you set header's content, when you set the TabItem's content?

Comment: @Ron; I can do that but the content is set at multiple places so I have to repeat that code is many places. Also if any other usercontrols get added then the developer will have an extra burden of remembering to add that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it. Not sure if this is the optimum solution so if anybody has a better solution than this then it will help me a lot.

I made a custom tabitem and overrided `OnContentChanged` (Didnt knew that there is an overridable `OnContentChanged` :)). So my code is like below.

```
    public class TabItemData : TabItem
    {
        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            if (newContent.GetType().Name.ToLower().Contains("mycontrolname"))
                this.Header = "control name";
            else
                this.Header = "old name";

            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM(or building tabs by assigning `TabControl.ItemsSource`) it is simple to do, just define an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text={Bindin Name}/>
   </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually I am simply assigning usercontrol objects to content. Tabcontrol already has a tabitem hardcoded in it in xaml. Something like this "tabitem1.Content = objUserControl;" So we are not assigning any ItemsSource to tabcontrol. :(

Comment: than show some code please, I believe it is possible to handle too, I just need to see some code

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**
 You can also use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` method. see: 
[system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx)

see: [wpf-why-is-there-no-isreadonlychanged-event-on-textbox-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607096/wpf-why-is-there-no-isreadonlychanged-event-on-textbox-controls)

also see this link: [listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx)

**My old answer:**
Create a custom class and handle OnPropertyChanged event. Sth like this:

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public MyTabItem() { }
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property.ToString() == "Content")
        {
            // here you are sure that ContentPropertyhas changed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TabControl XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl" >
    <TabItem Header="myHeader" Name="myTabItem">
        <my:customUserControl />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Binding the `TabItem` Header property in code:

```
// Bind TabItem Header
// Create a binding to a "Header" property in your ViewModel
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Header"); 
// Set the Source of the binding to your ViewModel
myBinding.Source = myViewModel;
// Assign the Binding to your TabItem Header property
myTabItem.SetBinding(Expander.HeaderProperty, myBinding);
```